# How can I provide a signed iOS app IPA file to an organization for MDM distribution?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, mdm

I have developed an app for a company that will deploy it to their devices for internal use on an MDM managed device.  They have asked me to provide a signed IPA file to them.  I am a small company with no enterprise account.  Also because the users are often changing they asked me to allow it to be used on 'all devices' and assured me they have strict controls to prevent it from leaking out rather than a whitelist of the several thousand users.

When I archive and select distribute app, there are currently the 6 options in the screenshot below.  Up to now I have been using the release testing and providing them the IPA for testing.  But now I'm not sure how to go about providing a signed release version?  I have seen some articles about ad hoc distribution but I don't see that option anymore.  And it seems enterprise is only for large companies.  At a bit of a loss on how to proceed.

[image]

Comment: You should use App Store "custom app" distribution. You submit it via App Store Connect as usual, but in App Store Connect under "availability" you link it to their Apple Business Manager organisation id. They can then obtain the app via Apple Business Manager and distribute it via their MDM

Comment: Thanks very much.  This is my preferred way to distribute but despite being a large organization they have asked me to send them the ipa directly.  I will discuss with them again.

Comment: Unless they have their own enterprise program to sign the ipa there is nothing you can send them that is going to be of any use